# Is $\mathbb{R}^2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ infinite dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is it alright to assume that $\mathbb{R}^2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is an infinite dimensional vector space since $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is?

Comment: The statement is certainly true.  Are you asking whether you can use it without proof?  That depends on what class you are taking, and what your instructor requires.  A proof by contradiction will be very short, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The subspace $\mathbb R\times \{0\}\subset \mathbb R^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$. Hence $\mathbb R^2$ has an infinite dimensional subspace and thus must be infinite dimensional itself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, is is infinite dimensional. It is because all finite combinations of elements of a countable set remains countable and $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

Comment: (which also shows it is not countable generated)